# How to check does a list contains an int and negation of that int?

Tags: python, list, match

I have a list of int for example:

```
  list1=[5,-5,6,7,8,3,9]
```

and my outcome should contain:

```
  list2=[5,-5]
```

I tried to sort them like this:

```
  print((sorted(set([i for i in list1 if list1.count(i)>1]))))
```

But it returns only same values, for example

```
if list1=[5,5,6,7,8,3,9], it will return [5], but I want to compare it with its negation too.
```

Maybe you would suggest me to convert all negative values to positive like this:

```
def toPositive(alist):
for idx, ele in enumerate(alist):
    if ele < 0:
        alist[idx] *= -1
return alist
```

But it is not an option for me, because I have to work with the negatives.

Comment: Your code was almost there: `print(sorted(set([i for i in list1 if list1.count(-i)>=1]), reverse = True))`

Comment: Already suggested solutions are `O(n^2)` if done on lists - because checking whether element is in the list is `O(n)`. If you convert your `list1` to `set` before iterating, checking `in` will be `O(1)`.

Comment: Elaborate, what should be the result for this list `[5,-5,6,7,8, -5, 3, 9, -1, -9, -9]` ? should it collect just pairs or all occurrences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if -i in list1]
list2

Out: [5, -5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should done the thing.

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i*-1 in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option keeping your original idea of using `count`. It will generate duplicate always, that's why we use `set`:

```
list1=[5, -5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 9]
list2 = [abs(i) for i in list1]
list3 = set([(i, -i) for i in list2 if list2.count(i) > 1])
```